# convert into json object label value format

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have this below type of object:

```js
{
    2019-02-28 02:36:20: "5 minutes"
    2019-02-28 23:59:59: "Today"
    2019-03-01 02:31:20: "+1 Day"
    2019-03-02 02:31:20: "+2 Days"
    2019-03-03 02:31:20: "+3 Days"
    2019-03-07 02:31:20: "+1 Week"
    2019-03-14 02:31:20: "+2 Weeks"
    2019-03-21 02:31:20: "+3 Weeks"
    2019-03-28 02:31:20: "+1 Month"
    2019-04-28 02:31:20: "+2 Months"
    2019-05-28 02:31:20: ">2 Months"
}
```

And I want to convert it into:

```json
[
   {
      label:'5 minutes',
      value:'2019-02-28 02:36:20'
   },
   {
      label:'Today',
      value:'2019-02-28 23:59:59'
   },
]
```

I am getting only key and value by using this function below but I am unable to create that type of array. Please could anyone help me.

```
closeDate = Object.values(state.finalRequest.closeDate);
closeDateKey = Object.keys(state.finalRequest.closeDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Object.entries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and then map it in desired form using [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let obj = {"2019-02-28 02:36:20": "5 minutes","2019-02-28 23:59:59": "Today","2019-03-01 02:31:20": "+1 Day","2019-03-02 02:31:20": "+2 Days","2019-03-03 02:31:20": "+3 Days","2019-03-07 02:31:20": "+1 Week","2019-03-14 02:31:20": "+2 Weeks","2019-03-21 02:31:20": "+3 Weeks","2019-03-28 02:31:20": "+1 Month","2019-04-28 02:31:20": "+2 Months","2019-05-28 02:31:20": ">2 Months"}

let op = Object.entries(obj)
         .map(([ label, value ] ) => ({ label, value }))

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an alternative approach using **[for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)** to iterate over the input object:

```js
const input = {
  "2019-02-28 02:36:20": "5 minutes",
  "2019-02-28 23:59:59": "Today",
  "2019-03-01 02:31:20": "+1 Day",
  "2019-03-02 02:31:20": "+2 Days",
  "2019-03-03 02:31:20": "+3 Days",
  "2019-03-07 02:31:20": "+1 Week",
  "2019-03-14 02:31:20": "+2 Weeks",
  "2019-03-21 02:31:20": "+3 Weeks",
  "2019-03-28 02:31:20": "+1 Month",
  "2019-04-28 02:31:20": "+2 Months",
  "2019-05-28 02:31:20": ">2 Months"
};

let res = [];

for (const key in input)
{
    res.push({label:input[key], value:key});
}

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```